# DES-encrypting a string and converting to hex

Tags: php, encryption, hex, des

I am trying to find a way in PHP that can encrypt a string in hex using DES algorithm. The result I need should be exactly like [this page](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/).

All PHP codes that I tried gave different results than what I got in that page.
I tried this code for example:

```
<?php
function Encrypt($data, $key)
{    
  $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');
  return $encData;
}
echo strtoupper(bin2hex(Encrypt("12341234", "1100000120140129")));
?>
```

The result was: `0D54E1C0B08DCB90`. While in [this link](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=31313030303030313230313430313239&iv=0000000000000000&input=3132333431323334&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=4DC7D8B78F0F33A3), the result is: `4DC7D8B78F0F33A3`.

Note that `31313030303030313230313430313239` is `1100000120140129` in hex
and `3132333431323334` is `12341234` in hex.

Comment: Although I'm not 100% sure, it could be that that web encryptor is using just plain DES while you are using TripleDES. Anyway why are you using DES or TripleDES when you could use AES? AES is both more secure than both, and is faster than TripleDES. TripleDES was a way of making existing DES applications more secure. But if you are doing a new application, use AES. Also ECB is a no no. Use CBC.

Comment: Well, actually I will use this script to integrate with an existing application which uses DES algorithm to encrypt PIN numbers. Anyway, thank you @TomHeard for sharing your thoughts. I will be very grateful if you can help me to find the proper way to test plain DES rather than 3DES, because I've wrote so many codes but none of them gave the result I am looking for.

Comment: have you tried:
`mcrypt_encrypt('des', $key, $data, 'ecb');`

Comment: BTW, I don't get `BFB309964F5D0250` as the result with that link. I get `4DC7D8B78F0F33A3`

Comment: My bad... The result was `4DC7D8B78F0F33A3` not `BFB309964F5D0250`. I corrected the questions accordingly.

and yes, I tried to use `mcrypt_encrypt('des', $key, $data, 'ecb');` but the result is totally different `271D1FFA518B5794` and this exception was thrown `Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm`

Answer (score 1):

This code did the trick for me:

```
$keyA = "11000001";
$keyB = "20140129";
$data = "12341234";
$TMP = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $keyA, $data, 'ecb');
$TMP = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $keyB, $TMP, 'ecb');
echo strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $keyA, $TMP, 'ecb')));
```

I used two-key triple DES method to generate the exact result in this [DES calculator](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/) website.

1. Encrypt the data using the first half of the key (most left 8 digits)
2. Decrypt the ciphertext using the second half of the key (most right 8 digits)
3. Re-encrypt the ciphertext using the first half of the key again

Thanks to @Duncan for the useful help.

Comment: That is not triple DES that is 9 times DES, you sure those 'tripledes' parameters shouldn't be 'des'?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by the way PHP reads keys and data when you supply them as strings. Solve this problem by using code such as the following:

```
$key = pack('H*', "0123456789abcdef"); // this correctly maps hex to bytes
$data = pack('H*', "0123456789abcdef");
echo bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

This outputs `56cc09e7cfdc4cef` which matches the DES calculator ([proof](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=0123456789abcdef&iv=0000000000000000&input=0123456789abcdef&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=8CA64DE9C1B123A7)).

---

For those interested, I also used the following Java code to deduce what was going on. This prints the same result as the PHP:

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[8], "DES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipher
    .doFinal(new byte[8])));
```

Comment: I tried to use this method on my numbers but the results still not the same as the DES calculator link

`$key = pack('H*', "1100000120140129");
$data = pack('H*', "12341234");
echo bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));`

The result of this code is `56de399b8bebe0e9`

Obviously it differs from the one here [link](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=31313030303030313230313430313239&iv=0000000000000000&input=3132333431323334&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=8CA64DE9C1B123A7)

Comment: @osama.khatib ... well that's because you're using a different key. If I plumb those numbers in, [it's correct](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=1100000120140129&iv=0000000000000000&input=12341234&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=4DC7D8B78F0F33A3). For some reason, you keep seeming to want to express your key in ASCII. `31313030303030313230313430313239` will give you a different result to `1100000120140129`!!

Comment: well, you plumbed the numbers before converting them to HEX so you got this result, but if you try the equivalent HEX value the result will not be the same:

`$key = pack('H*', "31313030303030313230313430313239");
$data = pack('H*', "3132333431323334");
echo bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));`

Actually, this error will occur **Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm**

Comment: @osama.khatib The website you are using and the PHP code I've shown you require ***exactly the same input***. You just need to supply hex characters. You are confusing hex with hex-ascii. I.e the decimal value `10` is `a` in hex and `61` in hex-ascii (using lower-case values).

Comment: @osama.khatib I've updated my example in my answer so you hopefully realise we are using hex characters in both the function and the website.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Let's say now that I want to encrypt this data **3132333431323334** by using this key **31313030303030313230313430313239**, the function `mcrypt_encrypt` gives and error "key is too large" while in the website everything goes smoothly.

Comment: @osama.khatib Perhaps it moves to two-key triple DES when presented with a overly long key? You seem to want to use DES, so only pass in 16 hexadecimal characters and try not to worry how a particular website handles this edge case.